# Is there documentation on/can someone explain a nested join in TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, join

I'm not quite sure how to describe this, and I'm not quite sure if it's just syntactical sugar. This is the first time I've seen it, and I'm having trouble finding a reference or explanation as to the why and what of it.

I have a query as follows:

```
select * from
     table1
          join table2 on field1 = field2
          join (
               table3 
                    join table4 on field3 = field4
                    join table5 on field5 = field6
               ) on field3 = field2 
               -- notice the fields in the parens and outside the parens 
               -- are part of the on clause
```

Are the parentheses necessary? Will removing them change the join order? I'm in a SQL Server 2005 environment in this case. Thanks!

Comment: I hate that syntax and remove it whenever possible.  I see it more commonly when the nested join is a left join though. I do not belive the parens are needed but if I left the syntax I would retain them as it alerts the maintaniner that something unusual is going on. I would try this one as normal joins though and time the two results and see if the nested join is faster. If it is retain it, if not, get rid of this nonstandard syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join order should make no difference in the result set of a query using *natural joins* (outside of column order). The query

```
select *
from t1
join t2 on t2.t1_id = t1.id
```

produces the same result set as

select *
   from t2
   join t1 on t1.id = t2.t1_id

If you're using *outer joins* and change the order of the tables in the from clause, naturally the direction of the outer join must change:

```
select *
from      t1
left join t2 on t2.t1_id = t1.id
```

is the same as

```
select *
from       t2
right join t1 on t1.id = t2.t1_id
```

**However**, if you see a subquery used as a table, with syntax like

```
select *
from t1
join ( select t2.*
       from t2
       join t3 on t3.t2_id = t2.id
       where t3.foobar = 37
     ) x on x.t1_id = t1.id
```

You'll note the table alias (`x`) assigned to the subquery above.

What you have is something called a  *derived table* (though some people call it a virtual table). You can think of it as a temporary view that exists for the life of a query. It's particularly useful when you need to filter something based on something like the result of a aggregration (`group by`).

The T-SQL documentation on the `select`, under the `from` clause goes into the details:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499(v=SQL.100).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: I understand a derived table/sub query. Is the syntax in my question just a shorthand which allows omitting the `select * from` within the parentheses?

Comment: No -- the grammar for the `from` clause just allows parentheses like you see. A table source can be many things (table name, rowset function, user-defined function, openXML, derived table, pivoted table or unpivoted table. there are places where the parentheses might be necessary for disambiguation, but ordinarly, with "straight" SQL using simple tablename joins, the parentheses shouldn't make any difference. I'd worry, in fact, they they might throw off the query optimizer, forcing it to do things in a sub-optimal sequence. One should let the query optimizer do its job as a general rule.

Answer (score 2):

In this case they are not necessary:

```
select * from table1
join table2 on field1 = field2
join table3 on field3 = field2 
join table4 on field3 = field4
join table5 on field5 = field6
```

Produces the same result.

Comment: @IronicMuffin Your question has two ? marks.  "Are the parentheses necessary? Will removing them change the join order?"  How is that not a direct answer to your question?  +1

Comment: @Candie, overall, my question is to have the strange join syntax explained. But as you pointed out, you did answer one of sub-questions. I'll remove the downvote.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary in this case.

It's necessary (or at the very least, a lot simpler) in some others, especially where you name the nested call:

```
select table1.fieldX, table2.fieldY, sq.field6 from
table1 join table2 on field1 = field2
join ( select
   top 1 table3.field6
   from table3 join table4
   on field3 = field4
   where table3.field7 = table2.field8
   order by fieldGoshIveUsedALotOfFieldsAlready
           ) sq on sq.field6 = field12345
```

The code you had could have been:

1. Like the above once, and then refactored.
2. Machine produced.
3. Reflecting the thought process of the developer as he or she arrived at the query, as they thought of that part of the larger query as a unit, then worked it into the larger query.

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов It's not, that was a typo.